# What are all of these IPs addresses? Honeypots?

Tags: nmap, honeypot, arp

I was scanning my network (192.168.0.1-100) and I found many IP addresses that are not mine nor known, around 800 of them. I guess it has something to do with the ISP. After scanning the ips with nmap this is the result I get in most of the IPS:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.244.237
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
135/tcp filtered msrpc
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
```

They IPs are in a range 192.168.8.X - 192.168.252.X.

The ouput of arp-scan:

```
**sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 192.168.0.0/16**
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9 with 65536 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.10    xx:xx:xx:26:11:b7   (Unknown)
192.168.0.24    xx:xx:xx:85:7c:a6   (Unknown)
192.168.0.1     xx:xx:xx:cd:00:18   (Unknown)
192.168.100.3   00:00:ca:01:02:03   ARRIS International
192.168.100.1   40:0d:10:cd:00:12   (Unknown)
192.168.199.100 00:00:ca:01:02:03   ARRIS International
192.168.251.254 00:00:ca:01:02:03   ARRIS International
192.168.254.254 00:00:ca:01:02:03   ARRIS International
```

As I've read, those IPs might just be honeypots defaults.

Why the ISP has this IPS around? 
How can I be sure they are or they are not honeypots?

Thanks.

Comment: Those are local addresses... Why would you see them on your ISP? They would only be visible within _your_ LAN, not any other remote network.

Comment: Hello @forest thanks for your reply. I know those ip are local address. My question is why I'm able to ping as many as 800? What are they? I only have 6 devices in my LAN.

Comment: Oh that is odd. Do you have any more information about them, e.g. MAC addresses? The entirety of the `192.168.0.0/16` range is local, so it would be odd if it had anything to do with your ISP.

Comment: @forest  I updated the question with the arp-scan output.

Comment: This seems to be a special thing with the router you have. See this discussion about  [Arris TG1682G (XB3) Phantom Device](https://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Internet-Archive/Arris-TG1682G-XB3-Phantom-Device/td-p/2739646). Similar discussions can be found when just searching for the special MAC address `00:00:ca:01:02:03`.

Comment: Why do you think they are honeypots? Many of these all-in-one modems/gateways provided by ISP have rather odd services they did a poor job of setting up or something.

Comment: @multithr3at3d but how can I explain over 800 ip address they I can ping and nmap?